# getting compilation errors in java code to upload txt file on google drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to execute sample java code to upload a file to google drive which is provided  at https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart.I have downloaded jar files and put them in classpath and also obtained client ID and  client secret.I am getting following errors.

```
E:\>javac -classpath /path/to/google/lib/*:/path/to/google/lib/libs/* DriveCommandLine.java
```

DriveCommandLine.java:1: package com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2 does not exist
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
                                                   ^
DriveCommandLine.java:2: package com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2 does not exist
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
                                                   ^
DriveCommandLine.java:3: package com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2 does not exist
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
                                                   ^
DriveCommandLine.java:4: package com.google.api.client.http does not exist
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
                                 ^
DriveCommandLine.java:5: package com.google.api.client.http does not exist
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
                                 ^
DriveCommandLine.java:6: package com.google.api.client.http.javanet does not exist
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
                                         ^
DriveCommandLine.java:7: package com.google.api.client.json does not exist
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
                                 ^
DriveCommandLine.java:8: package com.google.api.client.json.jackson does not exist
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
                                         ^
DriveCommandLine.java:9: package com.google.api.services.drive does not exist
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
                                    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:10: package com.google.api.services.drive does not exist
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
                                    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:11: package com.google.api.services.drive.model does not exist
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
                                          ^
DriveCommandLine.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpTransport
location: class DriveCommandLine
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class NetHttpTransport
location: class DriveCommandLine
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
                                      ^
DriveCommandLine.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JsonFactory
location: class DriveCommandLine
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JacksonFactory
location: class DriveCommandLine
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
                                  ^
DriveCommandLine.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
location: class DriveCommandLine
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:30: package GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow does not exist
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                                                                      ^
DriveCommandLine.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable DriveScopes
location: class DriveCommandLine
        httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                                                                            ^
DriveCommandLine.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GoogleTokenResponse
location: class DriveCommandLine
    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GoogleCredential
location: class DriveCommandLine
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);
    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class GoogleCredential
location: class DriveCommandLine
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);
                                      ^
DriveCommandLine.java:45: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Drive
location: class DriveCommandLine
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:45: package Drive does not exist
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
                             ^
DriveCommandLine.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class File
location: class DriveCommandLine
    File body = new File();
    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class File
location: class DriveCommandLine
    File body = new File();
                    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class FileContent
location: class DriveCommandLine
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);
    ^
DriveCommandLine.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class FileContent
location: class DriveCommandLine
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);
                                   ^
DriveCommandLine.java:56: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class File
location: class DriveCommandLine
    File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
    ^
28 errors

thanks.

Comment: Do those wildcards (*) work? I though you had to name each jar in the classpath..

Comment: THANKS E:/drive>javac -classpath ./*;./libs/* DriveCommandLine.java helped compiling sucessfully. But now I am getting **execution error** as described> '**E:\drive>java -classpath ./*;./libs/* DriveCommandLine**   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DriveCommandLine
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DriveCommandLine
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(NativeMethod)  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)'